# No local access in Windows 2008 Server VPN

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn

I've already configured a VPN server(PPTP) on Windows 2008 Server. Everything seems to be fine and my vpn clients are able to connect to the network. Internet access works fine but there is no local access to other machines at my workplace which is the main reason we are setting up this vpn server. I used [this guide](http://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2010/10/how-to-install-vpn-on-windows-server-2008-r2/) to setup my server and I tried everything I knew ! I did this once on a Linux server but cant make it work on Windows. I know it's a very simple rule I need to set somewhere but don't know how !

Comment: I'm trying to access other machines using their IP address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to access other machines on the network by IP or DNS name?
Sounds like it possibly may be a DNS resolution issue.
Try putting the network DNS server IP into the IP settings of the VPN connection.